# graphical representation of source code

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I have some source code in C# that lies in a number of folders.

I need to understand this code as it wasn't written by me. Not only that, I want to learn how enterprise applications are coded. The best way to do that is if I have a graphical representation of classes, inheritance etc. I should be able to see the source code in multiple layers: e.g how classes relate to each other, how properties/methods in these classes relate and call each other, etc. I've heard of enterprise architecture and checked it out, but I don't understand what I've read.

Can anyone suggest something else?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If there is some code you are confused about, post it and we can examine it. To "learn how enterprise applications are coded" you will have to examine the source; try stepping through it in a debugger. What makes you think the "best way" is to "have a graphical representation of classes"? What does that even mean; text is graphical. If you don't understand something you've read, try posting it to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/; Stack Overflow is for source code.

Comment: see Visual Studio Architecture Explorer    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2010/05/11/visual-studio-2010-how-to-understand-your-code-using-dependency-graphs-sequence-diagrams-and-the-architecture-explorer.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at  NDepend? It can show you all the dependencies withing the code - eg through graphs;

- http://www.ndepend.com

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [Microsoft Debug Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/debuggercanvas.aspx) to get acquainted with the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio right click on project and choose "View Class Diagram".